# react app fails when deployed to GitHub-pages but works fine on local host

Tags: github-pages

https://github.com/naftalib/news-feed
Get a blank page, dev tools gives this error on multiple resources;
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

Answer (score 1):

In the end the problem was that the .gitattributes file was mistakenly deleted from the public folder when cleaning up files.